# Is component nesting introduced by multiple higher-order components an anti-pattern?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux

Is component nesting introduced by multiple higher-order components an anti-pattern? Does the use of multiple HOC effect performance?

example:

```
HOC: A, B, C, D

A(B(C((connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(D(Page)))));
```

Answer (score 1):

High Order Components is a way we have in react to share functionality between components.

**Do they affect performance?** Depends on what you are doing inside.
If you are doing too many things on them, probably, but really depends on what your expectation for performance is.

Remember, not to overcome with performance optimisations if your code does perform well, first test, then optimize.